# No internet access is down for both Wifi and Ethernet on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, internet, ethernet

My computer was working fine yesterday but when I switched it on this morning, the internet access was not possible anymore. The network connection works fine as I can access to my NAS and to other computers of my home network but internet access is impossible. I tried to use a wifi usb key. The wifi is working but again, no internet access. Can someone help me ? I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with all defaults settings. When I switched the computer off yesterday, I was connected through Cyberghost VPN. Can this have an impact ?Thanks in advance. Best regards, Régis.

Comment: After more search, I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iergu6AIook&ab_channel=Ubuntuguru and the fix worked for me. Have a good day everyone !

Comment: Does this survive a reboot? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes. It does. I think it was Cyberghost that messed up my configuration file. The computre works flawlessly. Best regrds,